# Add button to Outlook 2010 in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, outlook, office-addins

I need to add some UI functionality to Outlook 2010 via C#.

[image: Outlook buttons]

I already know how to add a simple button, like Unread/Read using Ribbon XML.
Now, what I need is to add a button like "Categorize" which has a small menu with several options.

When the user clicks one of the options, I want to open a corresponding form to fill out.

Two questions:

1. How do I add this more advanced button?  Is there any internet resource that explains this stuff?  (So far, I could find only a walk-through for a simple button, which works fine, but I need more).
2. The options shown when I click on this button may be different depending on some internal logic (i.e. I may want to disable one of them or not show it at all).  How is this done?
3. For the forms that are opened, is it easier to use WinForms or WPF, given that I am not familiar with either library, but know how to program in general?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

1. Create an *Outlook Add-in* Project
2. *Add New Item* → *Ribbon (XML)* and name it `Ribbon1`
3. Paste this content to XML file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
       <ribbon>
           <tabs>
               <tab idMso="TabAddIns">
                   <group id="group1" label="group1">
                       <splitButton id="splitButton1" size="large">
                           <button id="splitButton1__btn" label="splitButton1"
                                   getImage="Image1" />
                           <menu id="splitButton1__mnu">
                               <button id="button1" label="button1" getImage="Image2" />
                               <button id="button2" label="button2" getImage="Image2" />
                           </menu>
                       </splitButton>
                   </group>
               </tab>
           </tabs>
       </ribbon>
   </customUI>
   ```
4. In Solution Explorer → Properties → Open `Resources.resx` and add some images, for example:

   - Image1
   - Image2
5. Open `Ribbon1.cs` and add these properties to the class:

   ```
   public System.Drawing.Bitmap Image1(IRibbonControl control)
   {
       return Properties.Resources.Image1;
   }
   public System.Drawing.Bitmap Image2(IRibbonControl control)
   {
       return Properties.Resources.Image2;
   }
   ```
6. Open `ThisAddin` and add this method to the class:

   ```
   protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility 
       CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
   {
       return new Ribbon1();
   }
   ```

When you run the application an `ADD-INS` tab you can see your ribbon:

[image]

**Note**

- If you have to add new forms to show you can simply add new Windows Form to the project.
- You can add *Ribbon (Visual Designer)* too. Then You can convert it to XML by right click on ribbon and choosing *Export Ribbon to XML*.
- You can find more resources in [Ribbon Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386097.aspx) like:

  - [How to: Export a Ribbon from the Ribbon Designer to Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386297.aspx)
  - [Walkthrough: Updating the Controls on a Ribbon at Run Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608628.aspx).
  - [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Tab by Using Ribbon XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Reza!  One thing I still have not figure out is that I have to click on the arrow and not on the button itself to open the menu.  If I want the menu opened in either case, what should I do?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, this is split button and to open dropdown you should click on text/arrow. There are different kind of buttons and menus in the toolbox, choose the one which you like more :)

Comment: What I meant was that this button has two parts: the button and the arrow, each of which can be clicked separately.  If I click on the arrow, I get the menu; if I click on the button, then nothing happens unless I specify a callback.  This is different from the "Categorize" button, where the whole thing (button + arrow) acts as a single button opening the menu.  So  I was wondering how to get that behavior.

Comment: I know what you mean. So don't use a `SplitButton`. Just use a `Menu`. For example `<menu id="menu1" label="menu1" size="large"><button id="button1" label="button1" /><button id="button2" label="button2" /></menu>`